# flutter notification onBackgroundMesssage issue

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to add this following line but it gives me an error
`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);`
packages are also added.. but it gives an error like

````
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onBackgroundMessage'.```
````

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info, please? Have you imported FirebaseMessaging into your file, for example?

Comment: yes I have added the libraries

Answer (score 1):

You have used it incorrectly , use like below :

```js
final FirebaseMessaging _auroMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

//Method to register for FCM Messages
  void registerAuroNotifications() async {
    //Initialize Firebase
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    //Prasad Get User permissions on  iOS
    getFCMIOSPermission();

    // Listen for Messages
    this.listenToFCMMessages();

    this.getFCMToken();
  }
  
  
  //Method getFCMIOSPermission
  void getFCMIOSPermission() {
    _auroMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings(
        sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _auroMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("IOS Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }

  //Method to get FCM Token
  void getFCMToken() {
    _auroMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      _fcmToken = token;
      sendTokenForFCMtoServer(_fcmToken);
      print('Token : $token');
    });
  }
  
  
  //Method to register and listen to FCM messages
  void listenToFCMMessages() {
    _auroMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onMessage : $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onLaunch : $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onResume : $message');
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onResume : $message');
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution... but I have no idea about notification if you have any demo module then please let me know... and again thanks for your help

Comment: have added some more code for you , but you will have to go through the flutter plugin usage to implement (firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2)